# I can't modify User Accounts in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: user-management

In Ubuntu 13.10 why can't I modify User Accounts if I'm an administrator? It simply gets stuck when I click on User Accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking on the unlock button on the top right hand corner of the page (if you haven't).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify users information :

`sudo chfn (username)` and then you can modify its full name etc..

if you want to change password : `sudo passwd ( username)` and type the new password

Answer (score -1):

See the following links for a resolution to this problem:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200902
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good1.0/+bug/1242367

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.